# How to use locate to search for parent folder of a file?

Tags: linux, locate

For example I have this file in this folder

```
folder_x/folder_y/file1.txt
```

I want to do something like this:

`locate -xxxx file1.txt`

and get this

```
/folder_x/folder_y/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dirname](http://ss64.com/bash/dirname.html) that extracts the name of the parent folder from a full filename.

For example, if it is a single file,

```
 dirname $(locate myuniquefile)
```

In case of multiple answers you can process each single entry...
for example using [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to build your command and piping the output to a bash shell.

```
locate \.mp3  | awk '{print "dirname \""$0"\""}'  | /bin/bash
```

With *modern* bash you can use other construct too as the [here string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#HERESTRINGSREF) one:

```
/bin/bash <<< $(locate \.mp3  | awk '{print "dirname \""$0"\""}' )
```

Note: for security reasons ([trojan horses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29)) it is a good practice to use the full path to invoke the commands: so better `/bin/bash` then simply `bash`.